# How to render a NURBS surface mesh from calculated points?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, surface, nurbs

I am using OpenTK (a c# wrapper of OpenGL) to draw a NURBS surface calculated with Cox-deBoor algorithm. The algorithm gives individual points on the surface. How can I render the whole surface from these points? In addition, how can I draw a wireframe of these points?

Thanks!

Comment: So, what have you tried? How is your code not working? Do you have any familiarity with OpenGL at all?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to generate a grid of individual points on the surface. If your surface parameters go between 0 and 1, let's say that you generate points every 0.05. In that way you will have a grid of 200x200 = 40000 points. (from your post I get that you have already done this)

Then you can draw your surface using GL_QUADS, for every group of 4 points in your grid. For example your first QUAD will be:

- Surface.Evaluate_UV(0, 0)
- Surface.Evaluate_UV(0.05, 0)
- Surface.Evaluate_UV(0.05, 0.05)
- Surface.Evaluate_UV(0, 0.05)

You will have to do the same for every "cell" in the grid.

Finally, if you want to see the surface as wireframe, you have 2 options:
1st option. Use the code:

`// This option renders the surface in wireframe mode
  GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Line); 
  // This option renders the surface in shaded mode
  GL.PolygonMode(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Fill);`

2nd option. Use GL_LINES instead of GL_QUADS to draw the lines that will form the wireframe model.